# Python Server not working in Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, sockets, linux-mint

A while ago I wrote a server in python 3.6 on a windows 7 machine, and it worked there. I have since transfered the server to linux mint 18.3 Sylvia with Cinnamon desktop. For some reason, the program is not accepting connections, even after changing the port from 80 to 8080. I determined this from using internet explorer on another machine to diagnose network issues (yes I did put :8080 after the ip address). My question is: what exactly should I do in order to make the program usable on the linux machine?

Here is the code:

```
import socket
import sys
import os
from _thread import *

def filterHTML(data):
    count = 0
    word = ""
    loc = data.find("HTTP")
    req = ""

    while True:
        if (data[count] == ' '):
            count+=1
            break
        else:
            req+=data[count]
        count+=1
    while True:
        if (count == loc - 1):
            break
        elif (data[count] == '?'):
            break
        else:
            word+=data[count]
        count+=1

    return req, word

def getEnd(data):
    lng = len(data)
    location = 0
    for i in range(0,lng,1):
        if (data[i] == '/'):
            location = i

    newstring = ""
    for e in range(location, lng, 1):
        newstring+=data[e]
    return newstring




def threaded_client(Connection):
    while True:
        print("recieving data from client")
        try:
            data = Connection.recv(4096)
            data = data.decode('utf-8')
            print(data)
            com, param = filterHTML(data)
            if (com == "GET"):
                end = getEnd(param)
                print(param)
                if (param == "/"):
                    sendFileContent(Connection,"text","init.html")
                elif (end == "/favicon.ico"):
                    sendFileContent(Connection,"bin","favicon.bmp")
                elif (param == "/main/" or param == "/main"):
                    sendFileContent(Connection,"text","main.html")
                elif (end == "/BSS.png"):
                    sendFileContent(Connection,"bin","BSS.png")
                elif (param == "/Contact/"):
                    sendFileContent(Connection,"text","contact.html")
                elif (param == "/Projects/"):
                    sendFileContent(Connection,"text","projects.html")
                elif (end == "/cypher.png"):
                    sendFileContent(Connection,"bin","cypher.png")
                elif (end == "/stockOrder.png"):
                    sendFileContent(Connection,"bin","stockOrder.png")
                elif (end == "/website.png"):
                    sendFileContent(Connection,"bin","website.png")
                elif (end == "/background.png"):
                    sendFileContent(Connection,"bin","background.png")
                else:
                    sendFileContent(Connection,"text","404.html")
                Connection.close()
                return
        except error:
            print("client " + str(Connection) + "timed out")
            Connection.close()


def sendFileContent(connection,ftype,fileName):
    if (ftype == "text"):
        try:
            FileToSend = open(fileName, "r")
            FileContent = FileToSend.read()
            connection.sendall(str.encode((FileContent)))
            FileToSend.close()
            return
        except Exception as e:
            print("an error occured\n" + str(e))
            return
    elif (ftype == "bin"):
        try:
            FileToSend = open(fileName, "rb")
            FileContent= FileToSend.read()
            connection.sendall((FileContent))
            FileToSend.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print("an error occured\n" + str(e))
            return
    else:
        print("a thingir happened, don't know what")

connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
print("socket created successfully")
try:
    connection.bind((host, 8080))
    print("bind complete")
except socket.error:
    print(str(socket.error))
connection.listen(128)
count = 0
while True:
    clientConnection, address = connection.accept()
    clientConnection.settimeout(60.0*5.0)
    print("connected to: " + address[0] + " : " + str(address[1]))
    count+=1
    print(str(count) + " clients so far")
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (clientConnection,))
```

Comment: I tried the main part of your server code and it works for me. I suspect the problem is in using `hostname` (your hostname on many linux systems is bound to the loopback address only, not an IP address accessible from another machine). Try it with the host set to empty string -- that is:  `connection.bind(('', 8080))`. Then make sure you can connect to it locally from the command line with `nc localhost 8080`, then tell us what happens when you attempt to connect to it from another machine.

Comment: Also, for future reference, you should reduce your question to a [mcve]. You only needed the `import socket` plus the last 20 lines or so of code to demonstrate the problem. Anything that happens in your program after a successful `accept` is irrelevant to the problem you presented.

Comment: I tried what you said, I am able to connect to it using "nc localhost 8080", but not on the other machine

Comment: Other things to try: Find the IP address of your server, then *from the server*, try `nc x.x.x.x 8080` (substituting your IP address). That should work. Then take the exact same IP address. Go to your other machine and ensure you can ping the server: `ping x.x.x.x`. If that works, then use the IP address in the same `nc` command from your other machine (or if `nc` is not available on the other machine, use a browser with the URL `http://x.x.x.x:8080`). Pay attention to error statuses reported: "connection refused" is different than "connection timed out" for example.

Comment: I don't know what I did, but somehow it works... maybe I just need to not start up firefox before using the server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment, so:

Make sure that your ports are open on your Linux device. First check if you have a firewall up and running by `sudo ufw status`. If it's up allow the ports you want to access by `sudo ufw allow 8080` or `sudo ufw allow 80`.

As soon as your ports are open and accessible, there's no reason for it not to run.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I checked, firewall is inactive.

Comment: If the code is working (accessible) on Windows but not on Mint, it's highly likely connectivity issue. Most of the time the reason is the firewall. Can you install nmap via `sudo apt-get install nmap` and type `nmap -p 8080 YOUR_IP_ADDRESS` on the console? This should form the server correctly.

Comment: nmap says :PORT 8080/tcp STATE Closed SERVICE http-proxy        the server still has the same result